# Recommended way to Limit Azure Function Service bus Trigger Concurrent message processing when using App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-app-service-plans

What is the recommended way to limit an Azure Service bus trigger concurrent message processing when the Azure function is set to an App Service plan?
I know one can do it using "Max Concurrent Calls" when using consumption plan.

Answer (score 0):

To manage the concurrency of service bus triggered applications such as **Function Apps** and **Logic Apps**, you can use the host.json to set such values.

Attached below is a an example of settings that can be set:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "prefetchCount": 100,
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": true,
                "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
            },
            "sessionHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": false,
                "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
                "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
            },
            "batchOptions": {
                "maxMessageCount": 1000,
                "operationTimeout": "00:01:00",
                "autoComplete": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here (learn.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=isolated-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eric! :) Just a control question, i stumbled over something similar in example bu that was only in relation to function apps created in relation to consumption plans, does this also apply to App Service Plan based Functions?

Comment: This do work on App Service Plan based Function runtimes, yes. We do use it on some of our logic apps (same engine/service in the background as on FA's), and it works perfect :)